# AzureKeyvault ContainerClient missing required connection details

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-keyvault

I'm trying to create an Azure Storage ContainerClient within am Azure Function with following code:

Imports:

```
from azure.storage.blob import ContainerClient
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
```

In Azure Function:

```
# initialize credentials
default_credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

# connect to key vault and authenticate
my_key_vault = SecretClient (
    vault_url = "https://my-keyvault.vault.azure.net/",
    credential = default_credential
)

# grab the blob connection string
blob_connection_string = my_key_vault.get_secret (
    name = "mystoragesecret"
)
    
# create container client
container_client = ContainerClient.from_connection_string (
    conn_str=blob_connection_string.value,
    container_name="my-container"
   )
```

When creating the `ContainerClient`, the code throws a `ValueError("Connection string missing required connection details.")`
[image]

All required parameters are passed - signature according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.containerclient?view=azure-python#azure-storage-blob-containerclient-from-container-url):

`from_connection_string(conn_str: str, container_name: str, credential: Optional[Any] = None, **kwargs: Any) -> ClassType`

What am I missing here?

Comment: If you print `blob_connection_string.value`, what is the value that you see?

Comment: I used the Container SAS Token: sp=r&st=2022-04-07T06:36:32Z&se=2022-04-07T14:36:32Z&spr=https&sv=2020-08-04&sr=c&sig=CKuH.......

Comment: Your question made me think if I used the right connection string. I then used the in from the storage acct and it was fine. Thank you for pointing me into the right direction